# How can I ref a variable in ImportValue in cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a cloudformation template and need to import a value based on passed in parameter. Below is the code. But I can't combine `!ImportValue` and `!Ref`. How can I use the `EnvironmentName` in `ImportValue` function?

```
Parameters:

    EnvironmentName:
        Description: An environment name 
        Type: String

...

VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - !ImportValue # how can I reference EnvironmentName
...
```

Comment: Hi. How did it go with this issue? Any of the answers was helpful to combat it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say `Environment` is a Parameter in both templates

Security Group in Template 1:

```
MySecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
        GroupName: !Sub 'My Group - ${Environment}'
        GroupDescription: 'my group'
        SecurityGroupIngress:
            - IpProtocol: 'icmp'
              FromPort: '-1'
              ToPort: '-1'
              CidrIp: '0.0.0.0/0'
```

Exported from Template 1:

```
MySecurityGroup:
    Description: 'Security Group Test'
    Value: !Ref 'MySecurityGroup'
    Export:
        Name: !Sub 'MySecurityGroup-${Environment}'
```

Imported as

```
VpcConfig:
    SecurityGroupIds:
                - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub MySecurityGroup-${Environment}
```

Answer (score 2):

As shown in the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html) you can use `ImportValue` with `Sub` to achieve what you want:

```
VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - Fn::ImportValue: 
              !Sub "${EnvironmentName}"
```

You may need to adjust indentations to match your template.